# Вода из-под крана или из крана?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Задумался: а как правильно говорить - "вода из крана" или "вода из-под крана". Если предлагать свою версию, то мне кажется, что "из-под крана" можно сказать о воде, уже набранной. То есть, например: "Это вода из родника?" "Нет, это вода из-под крана". Но, когда нам надо обозначить, откуда именно течет вода, то лучше сказать, что "вода течет из крана".
Прав я или все-таки тут другие нюансы?

Answer (score 1):

Не пейте воду из-под крана! Из крана течет грязная вода.